# Python replacing string given a word

Tags: python

Hi does anyone know how to make a function that replaces every alphabetic character in a string with a character from a given word (repeated indefinitely). If a character is not alphabetic it should stay where it is. Also this has to be done without importing anything.

```
def replace_string(string,word)
'''
>>>replace_string('my name is','abc')
'ab cabc ab'
```

So far i come up with:

```
def replace_string(string,word):
    new=''
    for i in string:
        if i.isalpha():
            new=new+word
        else: new=new+i
    print(new)
```

but, this function just prints 'abcabc abcabcabcabc abcabc' instead of 'ab cabc ab'

Comment: i need to replace every alphabetic character in the string with a given word

Comment: Should a three-letter word be turned into `'hih'`?

Comment: not sure we understand the question

Comment: what do you not understand

Comment: The rules for replacing are unclear (and your comment below talks about punctuation which you haven't covered at all). Some examples: Should `"are you"` become `"hih ihi"` or `"hih hih"`? If some punctuation like `'` is supposed to be removed, what exactly do you consider as punctuation characters? What should happen with other characters? Etc.

Comment: 'are you' should become 'hih ihi' and the puntuation is not supposed to removed. Their was a typo in the comment

Answer (score 1):

Change as follows:

```
def replace(string, word):
    new, pos = '', 0
    for c in string:
        if c.isalpha():
            new += word[pos%len(word)]  # rotate through replacement string
            pos += 1  # increment position in current word
        else: 
            new += c
            pos = 0  # reset position in current word
    return new

>>> replace('my name is greg', 'hi')
'hi hihi hi hihi'
```

Comment: @James: Please clarify your question, then. There was no mention in it how to handle punctuation, least of all to silently remove it.

Comment: anything thats not alphabetic should remain where it is, and the alphabets should be replaced as shown above

Comment: @James: So why are you expecting `"hi hihi hi hihi"` as output from `replace("m'y nam'e is greg", 'hi')`, then? You're contradicting yourself here.

Comment: yes you are right, thats the typo, the correct should 'h'i hih'i hi hihi

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), first create a generator function that will cycle through your replacement word indefinitely:

```
def cycle(string):
    while True:
        for c in string:
            yield c
```

Then, adjust your existing function just a little bit:

```
def replace_string(string,word):
    new=''
    repl = cycle(word)
    for i in string:
        if i.isalpha():
            new = new + next(repl)
        else: 
            new = new+i
    return new
```

Output:

```
>>> replace_string("Hello, I'm Greg, are you ok?", "hi")
"hihih, i'h ihih, ihi hih ih?"
```

Another way to write this (but I think the first version is more readable and therefore better):

```
def replace_string(string,word):
    return ''.join(next(cycle(word)) if c.isalpha() else c for c in string)
```

Comment: im not allowed to import anything

Comment: Why didn't you say so in your question? Please edit your question to add all relevant details/constraints to it. Don't spread crucial information through the comments.

Comment: i have been adjusting the main question